# System.ServiceModel.FaultException in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, wcf-data-services

I am getting the following error in my **WCF Service**:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[WcfJMMLib.JMMPackage]: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

After several hours of debugging the issue could be temporarily resolved by replacing the config file in the hosted folder (pointing to IIS) or running IISRESET command. This issue repeats after some calls again. What is with replacing the config file that is giving the error.

**Config file**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

```
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="21474083647" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="83808608" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="409600000" maxNameTableCharCount="163840000" />



    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="100000000" maxBytesPerRead="409600000" maxNameTableCharCount="163840000"/>

    </binding>

  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="servicebehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restbehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>


<services>
  <service name="WcfJMMLib.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="servicebehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--<add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfJMMLib/Service1/" />-->
        <add baseAddress = "http://mngnet371715d.ad.infosys.com/WcfJMMLib/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfJMMLib.IService1">


      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="WcfJMMLib.IService2"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior" contract="WcfJMMLib.IService2"/>
    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
    <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <!--<endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" name="webEndPoint" contract="WcfJMMLib.IService1"/>-->

  </service>
</services>

 </system.serviceModel>
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  </defaultProxy>
  <connectionManagement>
  <add maxconnection = "100" address ="*" />
  </connectionManagement>
 </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can turn on WCF tracing in order to see more detailed Informations about this issue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx